# For an n-Gram model with n>2, do we need more context at end of each sentence?

Tags: nlp, language-model, stanford-nlp, ngrams

Jurafsky's book says we need to add context to left and **right** of a sentence:

> [image: "Note that for these larger ngrams, we’ll need to assume extra context for the contexts to the left and right of the sentence end."]

Does this mean,

**for example**, if we've a corpus of three sentences: `"John read Moby Dick"`, `"Mary read a different book"`, and `"She read a book by Cher"`; and after training our tri-gram model on this corpus of three sentences, we need to evaluate the probability of a sentence "John read a book", i.e. to find $P(John\; read\; a\; book)$ as below,

> $P(John\; read\; a\; book)$ 
> $=P(<s><s>John\; read\; a\; book<\backslash s><\backslash s>)$ 
> $=P(John|<s><s>) P(read|<s>John) \; P(a|John\; read) P(book|read\; a) P(<\backslash s>|a\; book)\; P(<\backslash s>|book<\backslash s>)$ 
> $=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{1}\frac{1}{1}\frac{1}{2}\frac{0}{1}\frac{1}{1}$       (without smoothing)

It would be great, if you let me know if the above understanding is correct?